# How can I retrieve username after someone connected via a .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I protected a folder on my website with a htaccess and htpasswd.

I'm wondering if it would be possible when the user has entered username/pass to retrieve the username and store it in a php variable so I don't have to make a html connect form.

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
```

PHP has a page to [document HTTP authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. I'll look into the $_SERVER variable, lots of good stuff in it.

Comment: [Here's some more PHP variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) that you might be interested in.

Comment: Didn't know about $_FILES, $_REQUEST and $_ENV. Thanks.

Comment: @Ping, best to just forget about $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` works?

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php